# Zendesk Ticket create API using ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, zendesk-api

BY THIS CODE PLEAS HELP HOW TO CREATE ZENDESK TICKET

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(function() {
    $("#btnGet").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://xxxx.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/1.json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
          "ticket": {
            "subject": "Tst SUB",
            "comment": {
              "body": "Test BODY"
            }
          }
        }),
        success: function(response) {
          alert("Hello: Success");
        },
        failure: function(response) {
          alert("Fail");
        },
        error: function(response) {
          alert("Error");
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: URL is wrong , you are adding a .json in url , please find the right URL and pass it with proper data required in data element. For making a HTTP call , we need Http method , url , input data.

Comment: What happens when this does fail? Error messages, anything in the console, etc. Try printing the response in the failure and error responses. (That might have to be fail, not failure)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have some issues with the body section.

```
"comment": { "body": :Test BODY" }
```

try

```
"comment": { "body": "Test BODY" }
```

Comment: Thanks to reply, but This by mistaken  write in question but in code it's right.

Comment: but Still not get solution if someone know solution pleas do.

Comment: Are you authorizing the request?

Comment: I have token but i don't know how to authenticate

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, the only mistake is in the request url. When creating a new ticket you don't need to add any ticket number.

Just edit the url removing `1.json` and leave `'https://xxxx.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets'`

Also, if you're not sending the request from within Zendesk (e.g. a custom app) you need to [authenticate](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/ticketing/introduction/#security-and-authentication) the request.